# Deployed program address is different from address made by `anchor keys list` command

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-cli

When I deploy to devnet I see a different address than the one I see when getting the list of keys.

Im getting not match program errors when trying to test it in code.
Error:
"Program log: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: DeclaredProgramIdMismatch. Error Number: 4100. Error Message: The declared program id does not match the actual program id"

Here's the structure
[image]

Comment: Did you replace the default program_id in your program?

Comment: @CryptoSar yes. I ran build, then deploy. Once deploy returned the Program ID. I set it in the lib.rs next to declareId and in the Anchor.toml.
I then ran build and deploy again. Before moving the idl to my app.

Comment: Can you tell me at what level of directory are you in when running ``anchor keys list`` command?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's gone over a year without a follow up. If this is still relevant, let's get some more detail!